# printing a toString() method output in a test class

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

Hi guys I have been making a test class for my word puzzle game and the out put is printing the objects reference number to the object. Anyone got the solution to print the return statement of the object.

Output:

> Generator stats: word-puzzles generated from words of length 3
>   Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@c68c3Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@b2002fPuzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@2a4983Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@406199Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@c7b00cPuzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@1f6f296Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@1df5a8fPuzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@b2a2d8Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@1e13d52Puzzle.WordPuzzleGenerator@80fa6f

Test Class

```
public class Test_WordPuzzleGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int sizeTest1 = 3;
        System.out
                .println("Generator stats: word-puzzles generated from words of length "
                        + sizeTest1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WordPuzzleGenerator puzzle = new WordPuzzleGenerator(sizeTest1);
            System.out.print(puzzle);
        }

        int sizeTest2 = 3;
        System.out
                .println("Generator stats: word-puzzles generated from words of length "
                        + sizeTest2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new WordPuzzleGenerator(sizeTest2);
        }
    }
}
```

Main program:

```
public class WordPuzzleGenerator {
    static ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public WordPuzzleGenerator(int size) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> puzzleListY = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> puzzleListX = new ArrayList<String>();
        String randomXWord;
        String letterSize = "" + size;
        makeLetterWordList(letterSize);
        boolean finished = false;
        while ( !finished ) {
            finished = true;
            puzzleListX.clear();
            puzzleListY.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int randomYWord = randomInteger(wordList.size());
                String item = wordList.get(randomYWord);
                puzzleListY.add(item);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < puzzleListY.size(); i++) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < puzzleListY.size(); j++) {
                    sb.append(puzzleListY.get(j).charAt(i));
                }
                randomXWord = sb.toString();
                if (!wordList.contains(randomXWord) && !puzzleListY.contains(randomXWord)) {
                    finished = false;
                    break;
                }
                puzzleListX.add(randomXWord);

            }




        }
        toString(puzzleListX, puzzleListY);
    }

    public static int randomInteger(int size) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(size);
        return randomNum;
    }



    public static void makeLetterWordList(String letterSize) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner letterScanner = new Scanner( new File (letterSize + "LetterWords.txt"));
        wordList.clear();
        while (letterScanner.hasNext()){
            wordList.add(letterScanner.next());
        }
        letterScanner.close();
    }

    public static String toString(ArrayList<String> ArrayList1, ArrayList<String> ArrayList2){
        StringBuilder group1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList1.size(); i++) {
            group1.append(ArrayList1.get(i) + " ");
        }
        String wordsInString1 = group1.toString();

        StringBuilder group2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList2.size(); i++) {
            group2.append(ArrayList2.get(i) + " ");
        }
        String wordsInString2 = group2.toString();

        return String.format("\t( %s) ( %s)", wordsInString1, wordsInString2);
    }
}
```

Comment: also your main program is only an object, your test is the main, you have it kindoff mixed up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `WordPuzzleGenerator` class does not override `Object`'s `toString`. Instead it contains a static `toString` method with a different signature.

You need a method of this signature in your `WordPuzzleGenerator` class :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    ...
}
```

After taking another look, it appers your `WordPuzzleGenerator` has only static methods and no instance members, so it's unclear what you expect `toString` to return, or in other words - it's not clear what `System.out.print(puzzle);` is expected to print.

EDIT:

If you want `toString()` to print the Lists created in your constructor, you should make them instance members :

```
ArrayList<String> puzzleListY;
ArrayList<String> puzzleListX;
public WordPuzzleGenerator(int size) throws FileNotFoundException {
    puzzleListY = new ArrayList<String>();
    puzzleListX = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

Then you can override toString like this :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return WordPuzzleGenerator.toString (puzzleListX,puzzleListY);
}
```

Comment: I want the toString to return a string version of the contents of both arrays

Comment: @Jackson That's what you static toString method appears to be doing, but when you write `System.out.print(puzzle);` that's not the method being called. You can call it explicitly with `System.out.print(WordPuzzleGenerator.toString(list1,list2))`, but you'll have to pass the lists to it. If you want to print the lists that you declare inside the WordPuzzleGenerator constructor, you should change those lists to be instance variables instead of local variables.

Comment: @Jackson Similar to it, but it shouldn't be static.

Comment: Oh I see now, Thank you for this help it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to override the toString method of your objects, since your object inheris from java object

```
@Override
public String toString(){
\\mystring build up...
return mystring;
```

notice the override annotation, thats what does the trick ;)
happy coding!

Comment: Then how to i reference the overide toString method to insert into my main toString?

Comment: The tostring is overriden in the object, in main when you go system.out.print(myobject) java calls that toString method.

Comment: And as the other answer suggests, you don't have anything in your object to toString,

Answer (score 1):

try to override 'toString' method in your class as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    //your code
}
```